# SOQL Select Statement within Select Statement in PHP

Tags: soql, php

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Name, Media_RO_Status__c, (SELECT OldValue, NewValue, CreatedById, CreatedDate FROM histories)
FROM Registration_Object__c
```

The response I get in php is:

```
SObject Object
(
    [type] => Registration_Object__c
    [fields] => stdClass Object
        (
        [Name] => a07j0000006iONC
        [Media_RO_Status__c] => Ordered UPC
    )

[queryResult] => Array
    (
        [0] => QueryResult Object
            (
                [queryLocator] => 
                [done] => 1
                [records] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => Registration_Object__History
                                [Id] => 
                                [any] => new005j000000Bv1WQAAZ2015-07-08T15:46:26.000Z
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => Registration_Object__History
                                [Id] => 
                                [any] => Cancelled RNAOrdered UPC005j000000Bv1WQAAZ2015-07-08T15:46:26.000Z
                            )

                    )

                [size] => 2
                [pointer] => 0
                [sf:QueryResult:private] => 
            )



       )

)
```

However, I want to traverse the array and get the formatted version of the string:

"Cancelled RNAOrdered UPC005j000000Bv1WQAAZ2015-07-08T15:46:26.000Z"

That string is actually output as a JSON when I run the original query in the Developer Console.

```
Example:
[{"OldValue":"Call Attempt 3","NewValue":"Rejected Cust Ordered Direct","CreatedById":"005j000000BvLm1AAF","CreatedDate":"2015-07-06T19:22:23.000+0000"}]
```

I'm obviously interpreting the returned info wrong, as the fields in the sub-Select don't come out as a sub-sObject.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try Once this i think you are accessing record from parent to child

```
SELECT Name, Media_RO_Status__c, (SELECT OldValue, NewValue, CreatedById, CreatedDate FROM histories__r)
FROM Registration_Object__c
```

Comment: Tried that, but it caused an invalid query error. My query does work as expected in the Developer Console though (the original one with 'histories')

Comment: if your object name history__c than append 's' at the end with '__r' like historys__r

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I only want to see WHO changed a picklist status field and WHEN they did so.

I didn't need the double Select in the statement, just querying the Registration_Object__History will do the job:

```
SELECT Field, OldValue, NewValue, CreatedById, CreatedDate
FROM Registration_Object__History
where Field = 'Media_RO_Status__c'
```

Does exactly what I need!